# Virtual overloaded operators >> and <<

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, virtual, function-definition

I need an interface that would require its subclasses to overload `<<` and `>>`, but I'm not quite sure how since these operators aren't overloaded as member functions:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, Student& student) {
    in >> student.name >> student.group;
    for (int& i : student.marks) { in >> i; }
    return in;
}
```

Maybe there's a way to make it a member function?

Comment: Declare a member virtual function for example like virtual std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const; And call it inside the body of the overloaded operator <<.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```cpp
class StudentInterface
{
public:
    virtual void readSelfFrom(std::istream& in) = 0;
};

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, StudentInteface& student) 
{
    student.readSelfFrom(in);
    return in;
}
```

And then let users derive from `StudentInterface`, eg:

```cpp
class Student: public StudentInterface
{
public:
    void readSelfFrom(std::istream& in) override
    {
        in >> name >> group;
        for (int& i : marks) { in >> i; }
    }
};
```

Comment: The `Student` is actually the one that should be derived, so I suppose that I leave `virtual void readSelfFrom(std::istream& in) = 0`.

Comment: @Ayxan nice! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

A general approach in such a case is to declare in the base class a virtual member function like

```
virtual std::ostream & out( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const;
```

In derived classes the function will be overriden.

Then the operator << can look like

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Base &obj )
{
    return obj.out( os );
}
```

A similar way can be defined the `operator >>` only in this case the virtual member function will not be constant..